# Google Maps alternatives for using in a Java Desktop Application

Tags: java, swing, google-maps, dictionary, coordinates

Does anybody know something similar to Google Maps for using in a Java Desktop Application? The only functionality I'm interested in is marking a point on the map and find the coordinates of that spot.

Comment: Can I ask, what is wrong with Google Maps?

Comment: One possible reason might be simply licensing issues - but I'm guessing of course.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283482/interactive-map-viewer-desktop-application-in-java

Answer (score 2):

You could use [TileMill](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/) and [MapBox](http://mapbox.com/tour/) to develop and host your map and JavaFX to embed the map in a WebView as Pulsar suggested.

Answer (score 1):

A popular alternative is [OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page). Unfortunately, I can't provide exact implementation details, as I haven't tried it yet, but it certainly seems to be possible to use it in Java, according to their Wiki.

Comment: openstreetmap is the second best maps in the internet today

Comment: Actually JMapViewer and MapBox both use OSM and I'm guessing so does TileMill

Answer (score 1):

See this question and answers:
[Alternative Map API's (Like Google Maps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609344/alternative-map-apis-like-google-maps)

To embed them in a Java app you can easily embed a webpage with JavaFX 2 webview (javafx 2 components can be used in swing too). Or use a library they provide (if any) or implement the api and rendering yourself.

Very easy example of how to embed Google Maps in JavaFX 2:

http://java-buddy.blogspot.se/2012/03/embed-google-maps-in-javafx-webview.html

Answer (score 1):

[`JMapViewer`](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JMapViewer), mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10744798/230513), works well in a Swing application, but I haven't tried it in a [Java Desktop Application](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsr296/info).